# Skorokhod representation proof understanding

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

The conditions 1-3 were that $F$ is right continuous, $F$ is increasing and the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$ is $1$ and $0$ if $x$ tends to $-\infty$.

I don't follow the idea of this proof, mainly how can we conclude that $F_X(t) = \text{leb}(w : X(w) \leq t) = F(t)$ immediately if $X$ is the inverse of $F$?

Comment: This is written: because $\{\omega\mid X(\omega)\leqslant t\}=\{\omega\mid G(\omega)\leqslant t\}=\{\omega\mid F^{-1}(\omega)\leqslant t\}=\{\omega\mid\omega\leqslant F(t)\}$ hence $F_X(t)=P(X\leqslant t)=\mathrm{Leb}([0,F(t)])=F(t)$ for every $t$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Did thanks for your response, could you elaborate on why $P(X \leq t) = \text{Leb}([0,F(t)])$?

Comment: ?? The whole comment does "elaborate" on that. Why don't you rather explain what you fail to get? See, there are 6 equal signs in my comment, can you name one which is not crystal clear to you?

Comment: @Did I highlighted the one which didn't make sense to me, and that was your "hence..." $P(X\leq t) = \text{Leb}([0,F(t)])$. I don't see how this follows from the previous working.

Comment: You know that $A=B$ with $A=\{X\leqslant t\}$ and $B=[0,F(t)]$ and that $P=\mathrm{Leb}$ and you are asking why $P(A)=\mathrm{Leb}(B)$?

Comment: I didn't realise $P = \text{Leb}$. thanks.